# Handling Java KeyEvents

Tags: java, swing, events, event-handling, awt

I'm writing a simple game in Java and I need to handle KeyEvents. Unfortunately my Java knowledge is considerably low and I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong here? I also tried to implement `KeyListener` while extending from `JPanel` just to see if it will work, I even overridden `addNotify()`
to `requestFocus()` and nothing. Everything else works fine.

The following is the class that should handle the events:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class BasicRobot extends JComponent{

    public static enum FACING{
            NORTH, WEST, SOUTH, EAST
    }

    int xLoc, yLoc;
    FACING facing;
    int beepers;

    public BasicRobot(int xLoc, int yLoc, FACING facing, int beepers){
        this.xLoc = xLoc;
        this.yLoc = yLoc;
        this.facing = facing;
        this.beepers = beepers;
        World w = new World(this);
        addKeyListener();
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    public void move(){

        switch(facing){
        case NORTH:
            yLoc++;
            break;
        case WEST:
            xLoc--;
            break;
        case SOUTH:
            yLoc--;
            break;
        case EAST:
            xLoc++;
            break;
        }
    }

    public void turnLeft(){

        switch(facing){
        case NORTH:
            facing=FACING.WEST;
            break;
        case WEST:
            facing=FACING.SOUTH;
            break;
        case SOUTH:
            facing=FACING.EAST;
            break;
        case EAST:
            facing=FACING.NORTH;
            break;
        }
    }

    void addKeyListener(){
        getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), "move");
        getActionMap().put("move", new AbstractAction(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                move();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the `World` class(not sure how relevant it is but maybe I have done something really stupid so here it is):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class World extends JPanel implements Runnable{

    private final int ROWS=30, COLS=30, BLOCK_SCALE=24, WALL_WIDTH=BLOCK_SCALE/3;
    private final Dimension DIMS = new Dimension(COLS*BLOCK_SCALE, ROWS*BLOCK_SCALE);;
    private final JFrame    frame = new JFrame("World");
    private final Polygon   NORTH_TRIANGLE = new Polygon(new int[]{5,BLOCK_SCALE/2,BLOCK_SCALE-5}, new int[]{BLOCK_SCALE-3,2,BLOCK_SCALE-3}, 3);
    private final Polygon   WEST_TRIANGLE = new Polygon(new int[]{1,BLOCK_SCALE-4,BLOCK_SCALE-4}, new int[]{BLOCK_SCALE/2,5,BLOCK_SCALE-5}, 3);
    private final Polygon   SOUTH_TRIANGLE = new Polygon(new int[]{5,BLOCK_SCALE/2,BLOCK_SCALE-5}, new int[]{3,BLOCK_SCALE-2,3}, 3);
    private final Polygon   EAST_TRIANGLE = new Polygon(new int[]{4,4,BLOCK_SCALE-1}, new int[]{BLOCK_SCALE-5,5,BLOCK_SCALE/2}, 3);
    private final int       obsticleMap[][] = new int[COLS][ROWS];
    private final Wall      obsticles[] = {
        new Wall(1, 1, 5, WALL_WIDTH, Wall.ALIGNMENT_HORIZONTAL),
        new Wall(1, 1, 5, WALL_WIDTH, Wall.ALIGNMENT_VERTICAL),
        new Wall(1, 5, 3, WALL_WIDTH, Wall.ALIGNMENT_HORIZONTAL)
    }; //The Wall class is just data nothing of interest there

BasicRobot robot;

public World(BasicRobot robot){
    super(null);

    this.robot = robot;
    initThis();
    initFrame();
    initObsticleMap();
}

private void initThis(){
    setBackground(Color.white);
    setSize(DIMS);
    setLocation(1, 1);
    setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
    Thread t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
}

private void initFrame(){
    frame.setContentPane(new Container(){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
        public void paint(Graphics g){
            super.paint(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON));
            g2d.drawRect(0, 0, DIMS.width+1, DIMS.height+1);
            g2d.drawLine(0, DIMS.height+2, DIMS.width+1, DIMS.height+2);
            g2d.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 18));
            g2d.drawString(String.format("Loc X = %d", robot.xLoc), 20, DIMS.height+22);
            g2d.drawString(String.format("Loc Y = %d", robot.yLoc), 20, DIMS.height+42);
            g2d.drawString(String.format("Beepers in bag = %d", robot.beepers), 150, DIMS.height+22);
            }
        });
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(DIMS.width+2,DIMS.height+50));
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.getContentPane().add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initObsticleMap(){
        for(int i=0; i<obsticles.length; i++){
            switch(obsticles[i].alignment){
            case Wall.ALIGNMENT_HORIZONTAL:
                for(int j=0; j<obsticles[i].span; j++){
                    obsticleMap[obsticles[i].xLoc+j][obsticles[i].yLoc] = 1;
                }
                break;
            case Wall.ALIGNMENT_VERTICAL:
                for(int j=0; j<obsticles[i].span; j++){
                    obsticleMap[obsticles[i].xLoc][obsticles[i].yLoc+j] = 1;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON));
        drawGrid(g2d);
        drawObsticles(g2d);
        drawRobot(g2d);
    }

    private void drawGrid(Graphics2D g){
        for(int i=0; i<COLS; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<ROWS; j++){
                g.drawRect(i*BLOCK_SCALE, j*BLOCK_SCALE, BLOCK_SCALE-1, BLOCK_SCALE-1);
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawObsticles(Graphics2D g2d){
        for(int i=0; i<obsticles.length; i++){
            switch(obsticles[i].alignment){
            case Wall.ALIGNMENT_HORIZONTAL:
                g2d.fillRoundRect(obsticles[i].xLoc*BLOCK_SCALE-BLOCK_SCALE/2, (ROWS-obsticles[i].yLoc)*BLOCK_SCALE-obsticles[i].width/2, BLOCK_SCALE*obsticles[i].span, obsticles[i].width, 2, 2);
                break;
            case Wall.ALIGNMENT_VERTICAL:
                g2d.fillRoundRect(obsticles[i].xLoc*BLOCK_SCALE-obsticles[i].width/2, (ROWS-obsticles[i].yLoc-obsticles[i].span+1)*BLOCK_SCALE-BLOCK_SCALE/2, obsticles[i].width,  BLOCK_SCALE*obsticles[i].span, 2, 2);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawRobot(Graphics2D g){
        Polygon translated;
        switch(robot.facing){
        case NORTH:
            translated = new Polygon(NORTH_TRIANGLE.xpoints, NORTH_TRIANGLE.ypoints, 3);
            break;
        case WEST:
            translated = new Polygon(WEST_TRIANGLE.xpoints, WEST_TRIANGLE.ypoints, 3);
            break;
        case SOUTH:
            translated = new Polygon(SOUTH_TRIANGLE.xpoints, SOUTH_TRIANGLE.ypoints, 3);
            break;
        case EAST:
            translated = new Polygon(EAST_TRIANGLE.xpoints, EAST_TRIANGLE.ypoints, 3);
            break;
        default:
            translated = new Polygon(EAST_TRIANGLE.xpoints, EAST_TRIANGLE.ypoints, 3);
        }

        translated.translate(robot.xLoc*BLOCK_SCALE-BLOCK_SCALE/2, (ROWS-robot.yLoc)*BLOCK_SCALE-BLOCK_SCALE/2);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillPolygon(translated);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawPolygon(translated);      
    }

    public void run() {
        for(;;){
            try{
                frame.repaint();
                Thread.sleep(40);
            }catch(Exception e){e.toString();}
        }
    }

}
```

PS: The preferred method is to use Key Bindings. Thank you!

Comment: 1) In your basicRobot you are using KeyBinding not KeyListener 2) You have to use `requestFocusInWindow` , requestFocus if you read the api is discouraged. 3) You are blocking the thread where the gui is running, to solve that try to use a timer.

Comment: The method `addKeyListener()` is never invoked.

Comment: Try using `getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)` and call `addKeyListener` a JoshM has recommended...

Comment: @Josh M It is I just deleted the line by mistake will edit in a sec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)` to remove any focus related issues...
2. Make sure you are calling `addKeyListener()` so that the key bindings are registered.
3. DON'T call `Thread.sleep` from within the Event Dispatching Thread

In fact, this looks suspicious...

```
public void run() {
    for(;;){
        try{
            frame.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(40);
        }catch(Exception e){e.toString();}
    }
}
```

Seen as you're not actually updating the state of anything,  all it is doing is sucking up CPU cycles which could be put to better use...

**Additional...**

Because you never add `BasicRobot` to anything that is displayed (like a window), it never registers it's listeners into the Event Queue, meaning, the key bindings will never work.

Instead of extending `BasicRobot` from `JComponent`, you should simply not extend it from anything, there is no benifit been gained.

Instead, register the key binding to the `World` and call `BasicRobot#move` from there

For example...sorry, I might have your code backwards a little, but the basic idea is there..

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class World extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }
                new World(new BasicRobot(0, 0, BasicRobot.FACING.SOUTH, 100));
            }
        });
    }

    private final int ROWS = 30, COLS = 30, BLOCK_SCALE = 24, WALL_WIDTH = BLOCK_SCALE / 3;
    private final Dimension DIMS = new Dimension(COLS * BLOCK_SCALE, ROWS * BLOCK_SCALE);
    private final JFrame frame = new JFrame("World");
    private final Polygon NORTH_TRIANGLE = new Polygon(new int[]{5, BLOCK_SCALE / 2, BLOCK_SCALE - 5}, new int[]{BLOCK_SCALE - 3, 2, BLOCK_SCALE - 3}, 3);
    private final Polygon WEST_TRIANGLE = new Polygon(new int[]{1, BLOCK_SCALE - 4, BLOCK_SCALE - 4}, new int[]{BLOCK_SCALE / 2, 5, BLOCK_SCALE - 5}, 3);
    private final Polygon SOUTH_TRIANGLE = new Polygon(new int[]{5, BLOCK_SCALE / 2, BLOCK_SCALE - 5}, new int[]{3, BLOCK_SCALE - 2, 3}, 3);
    private final Polygon EAST_TRIANGLE = new Polygon(new int[]{4, 4, BLOCK_SCALE - 1}, new int[]{BLOCK_SCALE - 5, 5, BLOCK_SCALE / 2}, 3);
    private final int obsticleMap[][] = new int[COLS][ROWS];
//    private final Wall obsticles[] = {
//        new Wall(1, 1, 5, WALL_WIDTH, Wall.ALIGNMENT_HORIZONTAL),
//        new Wall(1, 1, 5, WALL_WIDTH, Wall.ALIGNMENT_VERTICAL),
//        new Wall(1, 5, 3, WALL_WIDTH, Wall.ALIGNMENT_HORIZONTAL)
//    }; //The Wall class is just data nothing of interest there

    BasicRobot robot;

    public World(BasicRobot robot) {
        super(null);

        this.robot = robot;
        initThis();
        initFrame();
        initObsticleMap();
    }

    private void initThis() {
        setBackground(Color.white);
        setSize(DIMS);
        setLocation(1, 1);
        setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
//        Thread t = new Thread(this);
//        t.start();
        initKeyBindings();
    }

    private void initFrame() {
        frame.setContentPane(new Container() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                super.paint(g);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                g2d.setRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON));
                g2d.drawRect(0, 0, DIMS.width + 1, DIMS.height + 1);
                g2d.drawLine(0, DIMS.height + 2, DIMS.width + 1, DIMS.height + 2);
                g2d.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 18));
                g2d.drawString(String.format("Loc X = %d", robot.xLoc), 20, DIMS.height + 22);
                g2d.drawString(String.format("Loc Y = %d", robot.yLoc), 20, DIMS.height + 42);
                g2d.drawString(String.format("Beepers in bag = %d", robot.beepers), 150, DIMS.height + 22);
            }
        });
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(DIMS.width + 2, DIMS.height + 50));
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.getContentPane().add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initObsticleMap() {
//        for (int i = 0; i < obsticles.length; i++) {
//            switch (obsticles[i].alignment) {
//                case Wall.ALIGNMENT_HORIZONTAL:
//                    for (int j = 0; j < obsticles[i].span; j++) {
//                        obsticleMap[obsticles[i].xLoc + j][obsticles[i].yLoc] = 1;
//                    }
//                    break;
//                case Wall.ALIGNMENT_VERTICAL:
//                    for (int j = 0; j < obsticles[i].span; j++) {
//                        obsticleMap[obsticles[i].xLoc][obsticles[i].yLoc + j] = 1;
//                    }
//                    break;
//            }
//        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON));
        drawGrid(g2d);
        drawObsticles(g2d);
        drawRobot(g2d);
    }

    private void drawGrid(Graphics2D g) {
        for (int i = 0; i < COLS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
                g.drawRect(i * BLOCK_SCALE, j * BLOCK_SCALE, BLOCK_SCALE - 1, BLOCK_SCALE - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawObsticles(Graphics2D g2d) {
//        for (int i = 0; i < obsticles.length; i++) {
//            switch (obsticles[i].alignment) {
//                case Wall.ALIGNMENT_HORIZONTAL:
//                    g2d.fillRoundRect(obsticles[i].xLoc * BLOCK_SCALE - BLOCK_SCALE / 2, (ROWS - obsticles[i].yLoc) * BLOCK_SCALE - obsticles[i].width / 2, BLOCK_SCALE * obsticles[i].span, obsticles[i].width, 2, 2);
//                    break;
//                case Wall.ALIGNMENT_VERTICAL:
//                    g2d.fillRoundRect(obsticles[i].xLoc * BLOCK_SCALE - obsticles[i].width / 2, (ROWS - obsticles[i].yLoc - obsticles[i].span + 1) * BLOCK_SCALE - BLOCK_SCALE / 2, obsticles[i].width, BLOCK_SCALE * obsticles[i].span, 2, 2);
//                    break;
//            }
//        }
    }

    private void drawRobot(Graphics2D g) {
        Polygon translated;
        switch (robot.facing) {
            case NORTH:
                translated = new Polygon(NORTH_TRIANGLE.xpoints, NORTH_TRIANGLE.ypoints, 3);
                break;
            case WEST:
                translated = new Polygon(WEST_TRIANGLE.xpoints, WEST_TRIANGLE.ypoints, 3);
                break;
            case SOUTH:
                translated = new Polygon(SOUTH_TRIANGLE.xpoints, SOUTH_TRIANGLE.ypoints, 3);
                break;
            case EAST:
                translated = new Polygon(EAST_TRIANGLE.xpoints, EAST_TRIANGLE.ypoints, 3);
                break;
            default:
                translated = new Polygon(EAST_TRIANGLE.xpoints, EAST_TRIANGLE.ypoints, 3);
        }

        translated.translate(robot.xLoc * BLOCK_SCALE - BLOCK_SCALE / 2, (ROWS - robot.yLoc) * BLOCK_SCALE - BLOCK_SCALE / 2);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillPolygon(translated);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawPolygon(translated);
    }

    public void run() {
//        for (;;) {
//            try {
//                frame.repaint();
//                Thread.sleep(40);
//            } catch (Exception e) {
//                e.toString();
//            }
//        }
    }

    public void initKeyBindings() {
        getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), "move");
        getActionMap().put("move", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("move");
                robot.move();
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    public static class BasicRobot {

        public static enum FACING {

            NORTH, WEST, SOUTH, EAST
        }

        int xLoc, yLoc;
        FACING facing;
        int beepers;

        public BasicRobot(int xLoc, int yLoc, FACING facing, int beepers) {
            this.xLoc = xLoc;
            this.yLoc = yLoc;
            this.facing = facing;
            this.beepers = beepers;
        }

        public void move() {
//            try {
//                Thread.sleep(300);
//            } catch (Exception e) {
//                e.toString();
//            }
            switch (facing) {
                case NORTH:
                    yLoc++;
                    break;
                case WEST:
                    xLoc--;
                    break;
                case SOUTH:
                    yLoc--;
                    break;
                case EAST:
                    xLoc++;
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void turnLeft() {
//            try {
//                Thread.sleep(300);
//            } catch (Exception e) {
//                e.toString();
//            }
            switch (facing) {
                case NORTH:
                    facing = FACING.WEST;
                    break;
                case WEST:
                    facing = FACING.SOUTH;
                    break;
                case SOUTH:
                    facing = FACING.EAST;
                    break;
                case EAST:
                    facing = FACING.NORTH;
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Updated...**

This is a personal thing, but I prefer to use the `KeyEvent` virtual key codes instead...

```
getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), "move");
```

Otherwise I think you might need to use (but I'm not 100% sure)

```
getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put("pressed UP, "move");
```

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. I need the Robot and only the Robot to be created from a main method in another file without any connection to the World object which needs to be created internaly from within the BasicRobot class.
The "repainting" Thread is so I won't have to repaint after every change to the frame(it works fine when I call the Robot methods from main and not by KeyEvent).
I made the first changes you suggested but still nothing(will edit the post with the corrected code in a sec)

Comment: Yeah, I kinda hobbled the example together, not easy without a runnable example.  Swing uses a passive rendering engine for a reason, it's more efficiency.  Scheduling repaints only when they are needed will improve performance in the long run. Oh and will not perfect, the example does work, try it ;)

Comment: Ok it does work. I implemented your suggestion in the world constructor and it's all good. The thing is I still can't understand why the previous version didn't work. btw I did add the BasicRobot to the JPanel just deleted it by mistake.

Comment: @DimaMaligin The "main" reason would be how you registered the key bindings.  You used `getInputMap().put("Up", "move");` when you should have used something more like `getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put("pressed UP, "move");` - this is why I use `KeyEvent.VK_....` instead...

Comment: I did changed it to `getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put("pressed UP, "move");` and it still didn't work. Any way ty for you help. I will probebly spend the whole night reading on this topic so thank you again!

Comment: +1 @DimaMaligin a little recommendation, you should use `@Override` annotation, it's very useful with compile "typo" errors and make it more readable code.

Comment: @nachokk Noted. I'm not much of a Java coder more C++ and it's just a Collage project my friend asked me to help with. I don't think I'll be coding any more Java soon.